# Changing image Button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I want a back and forth changing image button with an ID tag just so my html5 can identify where the JavaScript should be redirected.

I need something of this sort.

```
function changeImage() { if 
(document.getElementById 
("imgClickAndChange").src == "
storage/emulated/0/ 
Documents/Mp3Player/html/ 
images/Pause.jpg") { 
document.getElementById 
("imgClickAndChange").src = "/ 
storage/emulated/0/ 
Documents/Mp3Player/html/ 
images/play.jpg "; } else { 
document.getElementById 
("imgClickAndChange").src = " 
storage/emulated/0/ 
Documents/Mp3Player/html/ 
images/Pause.jpg "; } }
```

But it needs to be able to change an image back and forth like this.

```
var newsrc = "Play.jpg";

function changeImage() {
if ( newsrc == "Play.jpg" ) {
document.images["pic"].src = "/
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html5/
images/Pause.jpg";
document.images["pic"].alt = 
"Play";
newsrc  = "Pause.jpg";
}
else {
document.images["pic"].src = "/
storage/emulated/0/
Documents/Mp3Player/html5/ 
images/Play.jpg";
document.images["pic"].alt = 
"Pause";
newsrc  = "Play.jpg";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
var element = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange")
var playPath = getPath('Play')
var pausePath = getPath('Pause')

function toggleImage() {
  if (element.src === playPath) element.src = pausePath
  else element.src = playPath
}

function getPath(type) {
  return '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Mp3Player/html5/images/' + type + '.jpg'
}
```

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. Could you potentially elaborate on what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create a fully custom mp3 player for a website but seem's to always need another code I'll show you what I mean

Comment: I'm a website designer that has been teaching myself for about 2 years but I still need to know about the purpose of not implementing all codes in one single file

Comment: I was wondering how to actually implement the 1st code like the 2nd code